# Do Saphirion Rebol 3 builds allow editable styled text?

Tags: rebol, rebol3

I have a an idea for a Rebol script I want to write, but for this I need styled editable text.

Does the current Saphirion Rebol 3 build contain the ability for styled editable text?

Answer (score 1):

Saphirion Rebol 3 build allows you to use rich-text dialect so you can make a script with styled editable text.
If your question reffered more to current R3GUI framework (also provided by Saphirion together with R3) then at the moment there is support for rich-text content like:

```
view [text [bold "Hello" red italic size 20 " world!"]]
```

but we don't have editable rich-text style(widget) yet. It can be of course developed by anyone who is willing to learn how to make own R3GUI styles.